# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'game' | how can I import stuff from a file that is in the exact same folder

Tags: python, file, directory, filepath

I am currently working on a project: a little game, text-based.

I made a folder called `game`, with all my files related to this project. I have several, and even the python code is split into a few files to make it easier for me.

My directory looks like this:

```
C:.
    boucle_de_jeu.py
    clss.py
    documentation.md
    fonctions_boucle_jeu.py
    idees.txt
    map_developpement.py
    meta_data.json
```

-->`boucle_de_jeu.py` is the main script, it contains the game loop
-->`clss.py` contains the classes of the game's items
-->`fonctions_boucle_jeu.py` contains a few functions used in `boucly_de_jeu.py`
-->`map_developpement.py` is the file where I create all the instances of the game, with the classes I imported from `clss.py`

I tried to run the main file `boucle_de_jeu.py`, and I got this:

```
PS C:\Users\...\python\game> py boucle_de_jeu.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\python\game\boucle_de_jeu.py", line 6, in <module>
    import game.map_developpement as map_items
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'game'
```

and these are the first lines of my `boucle_de_jeu.py` file:

```
# ...
import sys
from os import system

# ...
import game.map_developpement as map_items
import game.fonctions_boucle_jeu as fct_boucle
```

My question is, what are the ways to make this work? Maybe I should also reorganize my folder?

Thanks in advance for your precious help, have a nice day^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you mean to say all these files are in a folder called `game`, so the structure really looks like

```
game/
├── boucle_de_jeu.py
├── clss.py
├── documentation.md
├── fonctions_boucle_jeu.py
├── idees.txt
├── map_developpement.py
└── meta_data.json
```

Importing files in this manner can be a little tricky and you should be clear about what you hope to achieve. If this `game/` folder is in fact a module that will be used by other projects in the future, then (you need to include an `__init__.py` file, and) to import from other files in that module you should use the convention.

```py
from .map_developpement as map_items
```

However, if this is the entire project and you are only going to run files in this folder from within the folder, you can use the suggestion made by @jr15:

```py
from map_developpement as map_items
```

Note that these are not mutually compatible. If you wish to use the first option you will need to have all of your testing and whatnot outside of the `game/` folder and you will not be able to run files directly from the `game/` folder. If you go with the second option you will be unable to use the `games/` folder as a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

To import from `game`, you should have a file called `game.py`. I don't see one in your file list there.

Instead of this:

```
import game.map_developpement as map_items
```

Just do:

```
import map_developpemennt as map_items
```